# Navigate on clicking on HyperLinkButton

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone  8.1 App (WINPRT XAML)**. I added a **HyperLinkButton** and on clicking it, user will **navigate** to another page.

**XAML:**

```
<HyperlinkButton 
x:Name="Tile_ActivityTimetable"
Click="Tile_ActivityTimetable_Click">
    <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border 
            CornerRadius="6">
                <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/fit_0001_Activity-Timetable.png"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                    <StackPanel                     
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image 
                        Source="ms-appx:///Images/ic_activitytimetable.png">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock
                        Style="{StaticResource TileTextStyle}"
                        Text="Activity Timetable">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

**C#:**

```
private async void Tile_TheExercises_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ExercisesListingPage))); 
//this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ExercisesListingPage));
}
```

On **debugging** it gives an **Error**:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event
>   TaskScheduled.

Comment: Tried the code. It is working. May be its going wrong else where.

Comment: You have not Set to catch First chance exception in your Visual Studio.  Please enable it in debugging settings and please re-debug.

Comment: You should ignore the first chance exception, if you did not run into any issue. It's working for alfah, that means it has been recovered successfully.